# memcpy / sub list of linked list using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, memcpy

In legacy program I'm working on, there are several structs for linked lists as:

```
typedef struct Unit_Cell
{
    short           Type ;
    char            Name[x] ;
    short           X ;
    short           Y ;
    struct Unit_Cell *Next;
} Unit_Cell ;

typedef struct
{
    Unit_Cell    *Start;
    Unit_Cell    *Current;
} List_Cell;
```

I have a pointer to the List_Cell structure, which contains all cells.

`List_Cell *FullList; # malloc'ed, with added elements etc etc`

For a new development, I need to associate a subset of this full list, to new structures that looks like: (simplified)

```
typedef struct Unit_NewElement
{
    char            Name[y];
    int             Value;
    List_Cell      *ListCells;
    struct Unit_NewElement *Next;
} Unit_NewElement;

typedef struct
{
    Unit_NewElement   *Start;
    Unit_NewElement   *Current;
} List_Cell;
```

Creating a new element as:

`Unit_NewElement *NewElement; # malloc'ed, with added elements etc etc ...
                           # EXCEPT LIST CELLS !`

Looping on the full list of cells, I'm doing calculations to know if the Current cell need to be associated to my element structure.

Basically, we would do something like:

```
# Keeping the last element
Unit_Cell *Temp = NewElement->ListCells->Current;

# Replacing last element
NewElement->ListCells->Current = FullList->Current;

# Setting temp element (which is now our previous), next pointer to the new current
Temp->Next = NewElement->ListCells->Current;
```

But doing so, I'm literally broking the original "FullList" list.
**Which I don't want.**

I need to be able to add cells from the full list, for every NewElements I need, without impacted the full list itself.

Is memcpy the way to go ?

`memcpy(Element->ListCells->Current, FullList->Current, sizeof(Unit_Cell));`

How to handle the fact that there is also a pointer in the copied structure ?

And what about copying directly data without memcpy:

`*Element->ListCells->Current = *FullList->Current;`

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: To preserve the original list of `Unit_Cell` while creating the new list of `Unit_NewElement`, yes you could duplicate -- `malloc()` & `memcpy()` -- each `Unit_Cell` before adding the duplicate to the list pointed to by the `Unit_NewElement`.  But if the original `Unit_Cell` objects have a lifetime at least as long as the new list, then perhaps the new list should be a list of pointers to the original `Unit_Cell` objects. It all rather depends on what you want... which I agree ain't clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do in order to get a real copy of a list is a combination of `malloc` and `memcpy`, also the copied `Next` pointer must be overwritten.

Since I dont know how your sublist is created, I suggested something like a given starting cell and the amount of cells to be copied - then you could do sth like this:

```
ListCell *copyList(UnitCell *from, int n)
{
   int i = 0;

   if (!from || n <= 0)
      return NULL;

   ListCell *newList = (ListCell*)malloc(sizeof(ListCell));
   newList->Start = NULL;
   newList->Current = NULL;

   while (from && i++ < n)
   {
      if (!newList->Start)
      {
          newList->Start = (UnitCell*)malloc(sizeof(UnitCell));
          memcpy(newList->Start, from, sizeof(UnitCell));
          newList->Current = newList->Start;
      }
      else if (newList->Current)
      {
          newList->Current->Next = (UnitCell*)malloc(sizeof(UnitCell));
          memcpy(newList->Current->Next, from, sizeof(UnitCell));
          newList->Current = newList->Current->Next;
      }

      from = from->Next;
   }

   // Next-pointer of last cell still points to source list cell
   if (newList->Current)
      newList->Current->Next = NULL;

   return newList;
}
```

(I actually did not test this code so there might be some errors left)